# On Button Click in recyclerview how to increment counter and show in textview

Tags: android, button, android-recyclerview

I am working on an app that displays images using recycler view and volley.I have imageview, textview and buttons in each card. I am trying to add functionality to my button that when clicked, will count the number of clicks and display it in a textview. i am getting an error "variable 'count' is assesed from within inner class,needs to be declared final" trying to do this.What am i doing wrong? This is the code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Belal on 11/9/2015.
 */
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    //Imageloader to load image
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    //List to store all superheroes
    List<SuperHero> superHeroes;

    //Constructor of this class
    public CardAdapter(List<SuperHero> superHeroes, Context context){
        super();
        //Getting all superheroes
        this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.superheroes_list, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        int count = 0;

        //Getting the particular item from the list
        SuperHero superHero =  superHeroes.get(position);

        //Loading image from url
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView, R.drawable.image, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

        //Showing data on the views
        holder.imageView.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), imageLoader);
        holder.textViewName.setText(superHero.getName());
        holder.textViewPublisher.setText(superHero.getPublisher());
        holder.textViewLikes.setText(superHero.getLikes());
        holder.txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        holder.custom_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count ++;


                }

            });
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return superHeroes.size();
    }



    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        //Views
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewPublisher;
        public TextView textViewLikes;
        public TextView txtCount;
        public ImageButton custom_button;
        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);
            textViewLikes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewlikes);
            txtCount = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCount);
            custom_button = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.custom_button);
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place  `holder.txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));` inside onclick function and declare `int count =0;` below where you declare your class. like this

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
```

`int count =0;`

```
  //Imageloader to load image
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
```

Comment: button works with your solution. But all the textviews in all d rows are updated with the same number of clicks no matter which button was clicked. I want only d row in which d button was clicked's textview to be updated. @sachinMalik

Comment: for that you need to first set the data in the SuperHero class of the recycler view in the setter. then with the object superHero, call the getter of that method.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `TextView` not update the text every time when count value is changed. Try this: (not tested)

```
    private  final Handler mHandler = new Handler(); // globle variable
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) { // Note: final holder
    ...
      holder.txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
      holder.custom_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              count ++;
              mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run () {
                      holder.txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count)); // update new value
                  }
              });
          }
       });   

}
```